# Change Successful password reset message

Tags: customization

After password is reset in Wordpress, the message comes as "Your password has been reset. Login"
How do I customise this message?

```
        do_action( 'validate_password_reset', $errors, $user );

        if ( ( ! $errors->has_errors() ) && isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) {
            reset_password( $user, $_POST['pass1'] );
            setcookie( $rp_cookie, ' ', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, $rp_path, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true );
            login_header( __( 'Password Reset' ), '<p class="message reset-pass">' . __( 'Your password has been reset.' ) . ' <a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '">' . __( 'Log in' ) . '</a></p>' );
            login_footer();
            exit;
        }
```

This is the code I am looking at in wp-login.php. I just want to change the message alone. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [`login_header()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/login_header/) function, it appears that you can use the [`login_message`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_message/) filter.

```
add_filter( 'login_message', 'wpse386695_change_message' );
function wpse386695_change_message( $message ) {
    $message = str_replace(
        'Your password has been reset',
        __( 'The text you want to appear', 'plugin-text-domain' ),
        $message
    );
    return $message;
}
```

### Update

To replace the entire `login_message` string with your own URL (as requested in the comments), you can do this instead:

```
add_filter( 'login_message', 'wpse386695_replace_message' );
function wpse386695_replace_message( $message ) {
    $message = '<p class="message reset-pass">'
               . __( 'Your password has been reset.' )
               . ' <a href="' . esc_url( 'https://example.com/my-login-url' )
               . '">' . __( 'Log in' ) . '</a></p>'

    return $message;
}
```

...replacing `https://example.com/my-login-url` with the URL you need, of course.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! Any idea how to remove the Log in hyperlink that comes after the text?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the entire "Your password has been changed. Log in" text?

Comment: I need the message, but the login link to be changed to different URL. If that's not possible then remove the login link.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to change the text now. But the modified text shows up before resetting the password itself. When user clicks on password reset URL, the text is shown there on top. It needs to appear only after password is reset.